# Circular Buffer: Selecting Range of Indices that Include the Wraparound Point

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, circular-buffer

I think this question is best understood with an example. So here we go:

Imagine the following are defined:

```
parameter number_of_points_before_point_of_interest = 4;

logic [15:0] test_data = 16'b0000111100001111;
logic [3: 0] point_of_interest;
logic [7: 0] output_data;
```

if the value assigned to point_of_interest is 1 and the value to number_of_points_before_point_of_interest is 4. I want my output_data to be {test_data[E: F], test_data[5:0]} or 8'b00111100.

So in essence, I want to take 8 bits starting from (point_of_interest - number_of_points_before_point_of_interest) and ending at (point_of_interest 
 - number_of_points_before_point_of_interest + 7).

Since point_of_interest is a variable number, the following two indexing methods are invalid:

To make the code more concise: point_of_interest --> pot

number_of_points_before_point_of_interest --> num_pt_before_pot

```
buffer[pot - num_pt_before_pot: 4'hF]  // Invalid since pot not constant
buffer[pot -: num_pt_before_pot]       // Part-select doesn't work either
```

Note: Variability of pot is not an issue in the second case since starting point can be variable. Regardless, part-select does not provide the desirable results in this example.

Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: in the second case, 'num_pt_before_port' must be a constant. 'pot' can be a variable.

Comment: Yup, that's true. However, part-select doesn't work when you want to wrap around the buffer. I'll edit to indicate this.

Comment: in system verilog the **width** of a part select must be a *constant*. (there are no variable-sized wire bundles in hardware). If you cannot make it a constant, you cannot use this part select. Try a different approach with single elements (width == 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple trick you can do is replicate your test_data, then take a slice of it

```
  output_data   = {2{test_data}}[16+pot-before_pot-:2*before_pot];
```